# Custom file import into excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a flat file with an unusual layout, where the data is stacked vertically. Each block of data begins with the same literal string, but the preceding lines of data vary between each array. The goal is to flatten out the result to single records. I am lost on how to accomplish this. Please help.

Example data from file:
[image]

Desired final layout in excel:
[image]

The regular expression of which i want to break each record out into its own row is PL_ID%. I just don't know enough about vba scripting to do it. Can someone point me in a direction?

Comment: Read the entire file in a string, then split the string by "PL_ID", loop the resulting variant array and replace all `vbCrLf` with `vbTab` (except for the last `vbCrLf`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub flatToExcel()

Dim fileToOpen As String
Dim allData As String, parseData() As String
Dim currentRow As Integer

fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")

If fileToOpen <> "" Then
    Open fileToOpen For Binary As #1
    allData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , allData
    Close #1
End If

parseData() = Split(allData, vbCrLf)
currentRow = 0

For i = 0 To UBound(parseData(), 1) - LBound(parseData(), 1)
    If Not parseData(i) Like "PL_ID*" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(currentRow, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).Value = parseData(i)
    Else
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(currentRow, 1).Value = parseData(i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. I am experimenting with it now. Pardon my ignorance on the subject of vba scripting, but i made an Active x button control and mapped the code to it, and reading the documentation on Application.GetOpenFilename Method, i'm expecting a dialog to open where i can select files, but there is none. Am i going about this right?

Comment: Disregard, i figured out the issue. Marking this as answered. Thank you very much